# Ajax call is not working in keyup function

Tags: jquery, ajax

when I put alert before ajax call alert shows but doesn't show inside the ajax call  its not even getting inside the ajax call why its a php file and i'm using xxamp.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 pb-3">
```

<textarea. name="in" id="text" type="text" cols="30" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Write a message...">

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
<script>

document.querySelector("#scroll_msg").scrollTop = document.querySelector("#scroll_msg").scrollHeight;

</script>





$(document).ready(function(){
```

$('#text').keyup(function(e){

```
if(e.keyCode==13){   
    
var text=$('#text').val(); 
    $.ajax({
        
        type:'POST',
        url:'insert_msg.php',
    data:{text:text},
    
    success:function(){ 
        //alert('hello');
        $('#scroll_msg').load('display_msg.php'); 
        $('#text').val('');
        
    } 
        
    });
    
    
    
}
```

});

});

Comment: what is the "alert('hello');" doing in your ajax config object? its destroying the syntax.

Comment: anyway it does not work either I tried the alert in the success function instead ajax

Comment: and you do have jquery included and a textarea or input[type=text] with the id `text` ?

Comment: yes man everything is ok Its a textarea type = text and id =text

Comment: then you got to provide us with more of your code, since the snippet above is fine.

Comment: I tried to give more but I couldnt format it right  theres a textarea 
everything seems fine but it's not calling the $.ajax({ }); befor $.ajax everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

Remove <kbd>alert()</kbd> and following is the working code. (Obviously it will not work here as those endpoints are not valid for stackoverflow, but if you try in your environment, they should work)

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#text').keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==13)
        {    
           console.log('Event keyUp on enter');
            var text=$('#text').val(); 
            $.ajax({
             
                type:'POST',
                url:'insert_msg.php',
                data:{text:text},

                success:function(){    alert('hello');
                    $('#scroll_msg').load('display_msg.php');
                    $('#text').val('');
                } 
            });
        }   
    });     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text">
```

Comment: it still seems doesn't

Comment: Can you click on _Run Code snippet_ in the above ans, you should be able to see that it is entering into ajax and keyup event is functioning. And also can you share the console error that you see when you run in local?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.<anonymous> (sent_messages.php:92)
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.v.handle (jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ sent_messages.php:92
dispatch @ jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js:2

Comment: yes I know its getting the keyup event 
but I just noticed the error in the console its the problem in ajax or my Jquery version I dont know 
help me

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I finally got it nothing wrong with my code it's the slim minified version of Jquery
caused the problem, so I replaced it with only minified it works now,
thanks all.